# WPF - changing bound data according to other controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm trying to experiment with WPF, so I created some test window to see how it goes.
I got a window which holds a combo box with some options, and in the window there's a data grid which is bound to a property of a list of the combo box's selected item (meaning when you select an item in the combo box, the data grid is updated accordingly).

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=comboBoxPeople, 
                                Path=SelectedItem.OrdersList}"/>
```

I've added a CheckBox and a TextBox to the window and I want to use them in order to filter some lines in the data grid. The checkBox determines if there is any filtering at all, and the filtering itself is done according to the text in the TextBox.

How Do I filter the DataGrid's lines with the CheckBox and TextBox? I know I can make a MultiValueConverter with MultiBinding and return the new ItemsSource I want for the DataGrid, but I'm looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allItemsYou can bind the Filter-Properties of the Object that contains the DataGrid-Lines to the CheckBox and TextBox. Every time these Properties are updated, you update the filtering too. 
Additional you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface and and raise the PropertyChanged Event every time the List of DataGrid-Lines changes.

The class you bind to would look something like this:

```
class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private List<OrderItem> allItems;

    private string textBoxValue;
    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get { return textBoxValue; }
        set
        {
            textBoxValue = value;
            updateList();
        }
    }

    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
    private List<OrderItem> OrderItems
    {
        get { return orderItems; }
        set
        {
            orderItems= value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("OrderItems"));
        }
    }

    private void updateList()
    {
        List<OrderItem> newList = new List<OrderItem>();
        //update the List
        foreach (OrderItem orderItem in allItems)
        {
            if (orderItem[name] == textBoxValue) newList.Add(orderItem);
        }
        OrderItems= newList;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then how does the data grid itself show the new lines? Does the DataGrid's ItemsSource is supposed to bound to the DataGridItems property? But it's already bound to the comboBox. 
Also, how do I get in the updateList method the current lines in the DataGrid so I can filter them?
The data grid already holds some lines and I want to be able to do something like "if line[name] != TextBox.Text then filter the line"

Comment: if I understand you correctly every Item of the ComboBox has a OrdersList and you want to filter this list using the TextBox and CheckBox. You can achieve that by using a List of ComboBox-Elements and bind the TextBox and CheckBox to the selected Element.

Comment: As soon as you raise the PropertyChanged-Event, the DataGrid will fetch the OrderItems again and show the new lines

Comment: just one thing before I accept it... This solution as it is now is modifying the original list. I want to keep it intact and filter only the display of the data grid itself (meaning only its rows). Is there a way to do it without having 2 lists (one for the original list to restore it when I don't want to filter and one for the data grid display) ?

Comment: afaik this is the easiest way to do so, and since the List only contains references there is not much overhead in memory